# Trying to make my database more dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out what the best way to design this database would be. Currently what I have works, but it requires me to hard-code values where I would like it to be dynamic in the future.

Here is my current database design: 
[image]

As you can see, for both the Qualities and the PressSettingsSet tables, there are many columns that are hard-coded such as BlownInsert, Blowout, Temperature1, Temperature2, etc.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have these be dynamic. Each job will have these same settings, but I would like to allow the users to define these settings. Would it be best to create a table with just a name field and have a one-to-one relationship to another table with a value for the field and a relation to the Job Number?

I hope this makes sense, any help is appreciated. I can make a database diagram of how I think it should work if that is more helpful to what I am trying to convey. I think that what I have in mind will work, but it just seems like it will be creating a lot of extra rows in the database, so I wanted to see if there is possibly a better way.

Comment: Sounds like an *EAV; Entity Attribute Value* design, probably better asked @ http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93985/is-eav-an-appropriate-design-for-a-collection-of-coexisting-metadata-rich-fact

Comment: Yes EAV is what you are describing. It works and is incredibly powerful in the right situations. You might want to take a look at this article about a system that utilized this type of database structure. https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: The more generic the design, the less possible to ensure data integrity in the database usually. With your design it is easy to make temperature1 mandatory. Or not allow a temperature3 when there is no temperature2. Or to forbid certain combinations, say not to allow Sinks together with BlownInsert or whatever. You'd lose this with a generic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be best to create a table with just a name field and have a one-to-one relationship to another table with a value for the field and a relation to the Job Number?

That would be the simplest - you could expand that by adding data-effective fields or de-normalize it by putting it all in one table (with just a name and value field).

Are the values for the settings different per job?  If so then yes a "key" table" with the name ans a one-to-*many* relationship to the value per job would be best.

Comment: Almost every job will have the exact same settings names, but each job will have a different values for each setting. I would like them to be able to add more settings names in the future without having to change the database. It looks like EAV design is exactly what I need.

Comment: @LandonHammond That's what I meant, and clarified my question.  Then yes a one-to-many table relationship between settings and jobs seems appropriate.